# Write $\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{5b}}$ without denominator under the radical sign

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I am supposed to write the irrational algebraic expression without denominator under the radical sign.
$$\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{5b}};ab>0$$

> The given answer in my book is $\dfrac{1}{5|b|}\sqrt{5ab}$

My first try was to write the given expression as $$\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{5b}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{5b}}.\dfrac{\sqrt{5b}}{\sqrt{5b}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{5ab}}{5b}$$ I realised I am wrong, though, because we aren't sure that $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{5b}$ exist in $\mathbb{R}$ as we only have $ab>0$ which means that $a$ and $b$ can both be negative. How should we solve the problem then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have$$\sqrt\frac{a}{5b}=\sqrt\frac{5ab}{5^2b^2}=\frac{\sqrt{5ab}}{5|b|}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! What was the intuition that led to this approach?

Comment: The intuition that I should only deal with non-negative numbers, both in the numerator and in the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{\frac{a}{5b}}=\sqrt{\frac{a}{5b}\frac{5b}{5b}}=\frac{\sqrt{5ab}}{\sqrt{5^2b^2}}=\frac{1}{5|b|}\sqrt{5ab}$$

Answer (score 1):

the problem is when $a$ and $b$ are both negative,
in which case we replace them both by $\mid a \mid$ and $\mid b \mid$,
without changing the value of the square root,
since we multiplied what is inside it by $\dfrac{-1}{-1}$,
and then you can use your first idea. This reaonning hold when $a$ and $b$ are poth positive.